# 2d array in javascript post to the server via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have got a 2d array in javascript.

```
        var erg = new Array();
        for (var i in val) {
            erg[i] = new Array();
            for (var j in val[i]()) {
                erg[i][j] = val[i]()[j]();
            }

        }
```

but when i wanted to post it to the server only the 1d array gets passed. (erg[i])

```
         $.ajax({
            url: '/Document/UpdateTableValues',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                docid: documentId,
                page: self.CurrentPage(),
                elementid: element.Values()[1](),
                text: erg
            },
            success: function (data) {
                self.SaveState("Dokument gesichert");
            }
        });
```

how can i send the whole array to the server?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is just one mistake : use `text: erg +""` instead of `text: erg`.

Comment: this was not working. maybe i was doing something wrong on the server

Comment: public ActionResult UpdateTableValues(long docid, int page, long elementid, string [][] text){...} this is my controller action